# chromedriver.exe is ALREADY in PATH but still getting error message

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was writing on VisualCode studio, but I keep getting the same error message.

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.

Is it simply because you just can't run webdriver on vscode studio?

I've already tried

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:Users/.../chromedriver.exe")
```

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:Users/.../chromedriver.exe")
```

and basically every solution you can find online regarding this problem.

I've download chromedriver from here: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/.

I've also added the file in PATH by clicking "system">>"environment variables", and added the downloaded file containing chromedriver.exe in both user variables and system variables of PATH.

I've also tried coping the chromedriver.exe file in to the python3.7/scripts file, then added the file manually in PATH, then restart my computer.

Can someone please help me on this matter? or just recommended some place I can successfully run the webdriver?

Comment: C:Users/.../chromedriver.exe - is this the complete qualified path to the driver? The format should be accurate (e.g) C:/<Path>/chromedriver.exe

Comment: Have you opened a command prompt and run `echo %PATH%` to make sure the path to chromedriver.exe is in there? Sometimes the variables will cache themselves and adding a new one doesn't get detected.

Comment: @Sureshmani It was really"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\chromedriver_win32" I just left out the middle part for this question cause I think it's a bit long. Is this what you mean by the complete path to driver?

Comment: Your path looks correct. If you are convinced VS code might be the issue, you could always download a simple IDE like Atom and write a few lines of Python to see if you can get it working.

Comment: @Christine I did, and yes, those files are there.

Comment: Really weird. I'd try out a different IDE to rule out if VS code is the issue. Setting up chromedriver.exe shouldn't be this difficult.

Comment: @Christine thx, I guess i'll try that next.QQ

Comment: Just put it in c:\Windows. Make sure to restart all vscode windows when your ENV changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had te same problem and there is two ways to solve this issue. The main reason of this "*unreachable*" path is that visual studio code desn't have permissions to run from the path environment unlike any other system installed programs.

So by installing VS Code but the **System Installer** version would be enough. And the other way is by putting the ChromeDriver.exe file into the */Scripts* folder of your python installation folder (*i.e ...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts*).

---

I did both things and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Windows, go into CMD (Command Prompt) and type in "chromedriver.exe." If chromedriver is executable in PATH, the system will print out "Starting Chromedriver [version]..." Else, you need to chromedriver to path. Then again, it could just be a fault of the IDE, try using Python's built-in IDLE...