# chromedriver executable is in PATH but still getting error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, process-monitor

I'm trying to use selenium but I'm getting the error

```
'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

But I know for a fact that it's in PATH. I have the exe located in C:\WebDriver\bin. It's been added to my system variables
[System variables image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Hunj.png)
Running `chromedriver` in the command prompt successfully returns

```
Starting ChromeDriver 89.0.4389.23 (61b08ee2c50024bab004e48d2b1b083cdbdac579-refs/branch-heads/4389@{#294}) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

I've restarted my computer. I tried directly specifying the `executable_path`

```
driver = Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe")
```

I used ProcessMonitor if anyone can make sense of these [logs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18UyGHLqSWqvYPSJkxu8iUQ8vekch97GG/view?usp=sharing) (filter: "path contains chromedriver")

**Update:**

Using webdriver-manager

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Gave me the error

```
ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chromedriver.exe is ALREADY in PATH but still getting error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58752089/chromedriver-exe-is-already-in-path-but-still-getting-error-message)

Comment: unfortunately no @FluxedScript

Answer (score 0):

Try to use webdriver-manager package:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

the code should look like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

The module download driver automatically and store it at known path for selenium. It will solve all of kinda troubles with driver path

Comment: Using this I got the error: ValueError: Could not get version for Chrome with this command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version @Vova

Comment: @tape74 interesting, seems like there's a bug on it.

Comment: @tape74 does it work well with firefox?
`from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())`

Comment: Now the error: `SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Expected browser binary location, but unable to find binary in default location, no 'moz:firefoxOptions.binary' capability provided, and no binary flag set on the command line` my exe is in C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox tho

Comment: Solution suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318382/expected-browser-binary-location-but-unable-to-find-binary-in-default-location but I'm not sure how to use the options thing with webdriver-manager

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDriver\bin\chromedriver.exe')
```